# Is partial symmetry one of the most fundamental concepts or laws of reality?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, philosophy-of-mathematics

Brain is partially symmetric, planets are, most of the object that look symmetric, are actually partially symmetric. Is partial symmetry in some sense a fundamental concept of our mind or fundamental law of reality?

Comment: In what sense are the planets partially symmetric? Are you suggesting that the imperfection of the symmetry is what is at issue? If so, why? Nothing in the physical world is exact like it is in mathematics.

Comment: The question looks like a question in science rather than philosophy - ie it seems an answer is expected in terms of observations of the natural world.

Comment: I saw many water beetles in my childhood. Now, no more. It seems they've been kicked out of the city's ecosystem. 

Comment: @AgentSmith i eat snow in my childhood, but now i don't, it looks dirty.

Comment: @άνθρωπος, water beeetles and snow?!

Comment: @AgentSmith snowflakes are symmetry too)

Comment: @άνθρωπος, I don't believe that anymore.